# Why is MySQL CASE statement returning NULL columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I'm trying to display the results of a game in a pivot table. My results table looks like the following:

```
StageID StringID    ShooterID   FinalScore
------------------------------------------
    1       1       10041       6.579
    1       3       10040       18.008
    1       2       10040       13.639
    1       1       10040       9.895
    1       3       10051       15.464
    1       2       10051       23.842
    1       1       10051       21.018
    1       3       10041       13.601
    1       2       10041       8.151
    2       1       10041       49.5
    2       2       10041       59.5
    2       3       10041       49.5
    2       1       10040       69.5
    2       3       10040       39.5
    2       1       10051       109.5
    2       2       10051       89.5
    2       3       10051       99.5
    2       2       10040       59.5
... many more rows
```

To pivot the data I'm using a dynamic sql. Here is my script:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT group_concat(DISTINCT
    concat( 'sum(CASE WHEN `StageID` = ', `StageID` ,' THEN FinalScore END) Stage',`StageID`)
    ) INTO @sql
FROM
    `results`;

SET @sql = concat('SELECT ShooterID, ', @sql ,'
            FROM
                `results`
            WHERE
                matchID = 118
            GROUP BY ShooterID');

prepare stmt FROM @sql;
execute stmt;
DEALLOCATE prepare stmt;
```

Here are the results:

```
ShooterID   Stage0  Stage99 Stage1  Stage2
------------------------------------------
    10039   NULL    NULL    38.259  188.5
    10040   NULL    NULL    41.542  168.5
    10041   NULL    NULL    28.331  158.5
    10042   NULL    NULL    59.975  355.5
    10043   NULL    NULL    49.233  198.5
    10047   NULL    NULL    33.156  218.5
    10048   NULL    NULL    33.214  358.5
    10051   NULL    NULL    60.324  298.5
    10052   NULL    NULL    30.742  278.5
    10053   NULL    NULL    62.487  268.5
```

The problem is that I'm getting back 2 columns (Stage0 and Stage99) and I don't understand why. There are only 2 stages in the results table. Any ideas?

UPDATE: When debugging this script I determined that Workbench is creating the following string during the group_concat():

```
'SELECT ShooterID, 
sum(CASE WHEN `StageID` = 0 THEN FinalScore END) - max(CASE WHEN `StageID` = 0 THEN FinalScore END) Stage0,
sum(CASE WHEN `StageID` = 99 THEN FinalScore END) - max(CASE WHEN `StageID` = 99 THEN FinalScore END) Stage99,
sum(CASE WHEN `StageID` = 1 THEN FinalScore END) - max(CASE WHEN `StageID` = 1 THEN FinalScore END) Stage1,
sum(CASE WHEN `StageID` = 2 THEN FinalScore END) - max(CASE WHEN `StageID` = 2 THEN FinalScore END) Stage2\n FROM\n `wp_plinker_results`\n WHERE\n matchID = 118\n GROUP BY ShooterID'
```

Is there anything I can do to prevent Workbench from doing this?

Comment: Please, if possible; provide a sqlfiddle.

Comment: That's a case expression, not a case statement...

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to `matchID` in your select statement (the column in your sample is `StringID`), but otherwise the statement works as expecetd (on the small subset of data given), see here: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ecf3b/1). As @hjpotter pointed out, the reason may lie in the data (for `StringID=118`) itself, so maybe you can provide some more data?

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. In my effort to simplify the problem statement, I left out the MatchID column. When I add it to your sqlfiddle the query the statements run fine. It appears that my problem is related to the fact that I'm using MySQL Workbench. I also ran the script in phpMyAdmin and it ran fine there as well. Now I will chase the problem down that rabbit hole:)